# Access SPSS data from a Python, Java (groovy/grails)' or C++ app without license for SPSS?

Tags: java, c++, python, spss

I am finding mixed results googling. I have a need to parse a SPSS .sav file to discover the data layout and extract the survey results. Step one is to read the "schema" of the data. For example I need to know the question and its type of allowed responses. I plan to model this data in my own SQL table so I can slice and dice it per my apps requirements. Step two is populate my data model with the respondents answers. Looking at the SPSS sav file I believe it has both types of data I am looking for.

I don't need or want the expensive SPSS software if I don't strictly require it. We will not be doing statistics on this data, just selecting subsets of respondents based on answer filters. The SPSS file will be provided by a partner company that licenses SPSS. I do not need to out any data back into SPSS; my use case is read-only.

I can use Python, Java with or without Groovy, C/C++ for my parser program. This program will be run once at the end of data collection so performance is not particularly important. Ideally I'd like my code to be cross platform so I can develop on my Mac and deploy to Linux, but I can use windows if I must,

A lot of what am finding is either java classes from 2004 or modern Python code that requires a DLL from IBM and is windows specific. Based on my quick explanation of requirements, I would appreciate recommendations from the SO community. I think my needs are simple, but haven't found exactly what I had hoped. An open source lib would be ideal, but I'd even pay for a simple commercial solution at a reasonable price.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the SPSS i/o modules with detailed documentation for free in order to build your own app to read (or write) sav files.  The modules are available for all platforms supported by SPSS Statistics.

Go to the SPSS Community site at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/spssdevcentral and follow the links for SPSS Downloads.  You have to register, but that is free.

The SAV file is a binary format with a number of complex structures, so it is better to use the i/o modules.  And if new features are added to the SAV file, which has often happened, the i/o modules are updated at the same time, so your code won't go out of date.

HTH,
Jon Peck

Answer (score 1):

[GNU PSPP](http://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) can apparently read SPSS data files.  I also [found](http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/spss/3062/SPSS-File-Format) a link to [a description of the format](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/%2acheckout%2a/pspp/doc/data-file-format.texi?root=pspp&content-type=text%2Fplain) in the PSPP source, although it comes with a warning "don't try to read/write this format directly."

Comment: thanks. I'm downloading that now. I had seen that in my googling but was hoping for just a lib that would give me access from Python. But given I am perfectly willing to write my parser in C if necessary, this is a reasonable place to look. I'll check this out while continuing to look for a smaller component for Python or Java.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PSPP) that some of the PSPP features can indeed be used through a library, and since there exists a [Perl wrapper](http://search.cpan.org/~pdonelan/PSPP-Perl-0.7.2.20090730/lib/PSPP.pm) which can apparently read system files, it should at least in principle be possible to create a similar wrapper for Python.  Alternatively, you could perhaps write a PSPP script to read the data and output it in a more manageable format, and call it non-interactively.

Comment: So far my best option appears to be http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577811-python-reader-writer-for-spss-sav-files/ . I'm going to try it today. Only bummer is the window dependene so I my keep trying additional solutions. There appears to be an ODBC driver available too. So it seems there are options. Still open to more ideas or advice from those who have done this before.

Answer (score 0):

There is a java library here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/spss-writer/